# XML Manipulation and Injection

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

I've the following XML structure which is a part of a xml document:

```
<p:sp xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main">
....
....
....
<p:txBody>
 <a:bodyPr wrap="square" rtlCol="0" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"><a:noAutofit />
 </a:bodyPr>
 <a:lstStyle xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" />
 <a:p xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
   <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1200" dirty="0">
   <a:solidFill><a:schemeClr val="tx1" />
   </a:solidFill>
   <a:latin typeface="Verdana" pitchFamily="34" charset="0" />
   <a:ea typeface="Verdana" pitchFamily="34" charset="0" />
   <a:cs typeface="Verdana" pitchFamily="34" charset="0" /></a:endParaRPr>
 </a:p>
</p:txBody>
</p:sp>
```

I want to select **p:txBody** and want to inject **a:p** at the end, I'm using the following code but the **txBody** i am receiving is not the correct one, because i guess it's extracting that from the doc object not from the shape object:

```
        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("p", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main");
        XmlNode txBody = shape.SelectSingleNode("//p:txBody", nsmgr);
```

where **shape** is an XMLNode object having the OuterXml as mentioned above, and using the following code for xml injection:

```
        XmlDocumentFragment fragment = doc.CreateDocumentFragment();
        string xml = "valid xml";
        fragment.InnerXml = xml;
        txBody.Append(fragment);
```

but the injection is being done in wrong shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xpath isn't specific enough if it is getting you the wrong node. You need to give it more information to get the node you want. IE what sets the node you want to be different than the other(s)?

As you have it now, you are saying give me the first node you find that has the p namespace and the node name txBody **anywhere** in the file.

You have **shape.** but the **`//`** in `"//p:txBody"` says start from the root of the file.  If you mean to start from the shape, use **`.//`** so like `".//p:txBody"`

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ2XML. It's a complete replacement to other XML APIs.

```
XElement doc=XElement.Load("yourXML.xml");
XNamespace p = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main";
XNamespace s= "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main";

doc.Elements(p+"txBody").First().Add(new XElement(s+"tagName","value"));
```